# Dynamic updates with highcharts

Tags: javascript, mysql, highcharts

I'm working with Highcharts and Highstock from a few weeks ago. Step by step, following the documentation and help online, I have builded some charts with interesting options. But now I have a question, and my skills with mysql and php are limited.

I get temperature values from a data base, every minute. I use a php file to connect to database, and then I build the chart. Now, I want to update the chart like [in this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/edge/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/). But I can't find a right way. I was reading in Highcharts documentation, and Stackoverflow some answers, but I can't implement into my code.

I was working in 2 ways to implement the dynamic updates. The first one is:

```
<?php

     function conectarBD(){ 
                $server = "localhost";
                $usuario = "user";
                $pass = "password";
                $BD = "databasename";
                $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $usuario, $pass, $BD); 
                if(!$conexion){ 
                   echo 'Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la conexion de la base de datos<br>'; 
                } 
                return $conexion; 
        }  
        function desconectarBD($conexion){
                $close = mysqli_close($conexion); 
                if(!$close){  
                   echo 'Ha sucedido un error inexperado en la desconexion de la base de datos<br>'; 
                }    
                return $close;         
        }

        function getArraySQL($sql){
            $conexion = conectarBD();
            if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();
            $rawdata = array();
            $i=0;
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {   
                $rawdata[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }
            desconectarBD($conexion);
            return $rawdata;
        }

    $sql = "SELECT Probe1,Time from table2;";
    $rawdata = getArraySQL($sql);

    for($i=0;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){
        $time = $rawdata[$i]["Time"];
        $date = new DateTime($time);
        $rawdata[$i]["Time"]=$date->getTimestamp()*1000;
    }

    ?>

    <HTML>
    <BODY>

    <meta charset="utf-8"> 

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <div id="container">
    </div>


    <script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                }
            });

            var chart;
            $('#container').highcharts({
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
                    marginRight: 10,
        events: {
            load: function () {
                var series = this.series[0];
                setInterval(function () {
                    <?php
                        for($i = 0 ;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){
                    ?>
                            series.addPoint([<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["Time"];?>,<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["Probe1"];?>], true, true);
                    <?php } ?>
                }, 90000);
            }
        }

                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Tunnel temperature'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime',
                    tickPixelInterval: 150
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'ºC'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                tooltip: {
                    formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                            Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%b %H:%M', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                            '<b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 1) +'</b>';
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Probe-1',
                    data: (function() {
                       var data = [];
                        <?php
                            for($i = 0 ;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){
                        ?>
                        data.push([<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["Time"];?>,<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["Probe1"];?>]);
                        <?php } ?>
                    return data;
                    })()
                }]
            });
        });

    });


    </script>
    </html>
```

And this other way:

Connection to datatest2.php:

```
<?php
    //convert the date values to Unix Timestamp
    //Convert from 2017-02-28 19:30:01 to Tuesday, February 28 2017 19:30:01
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password"); 
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); } mysql_select_db("databasename", $con); 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table2"); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $uts=strtotime($row['Time']);   //convertir a Unix Timestamp
    $date=date("l, F j Y H:i:s",$uts);
    //echo $valor3 . “\t” . $row[$valor2]. “\n”;
    echo $date . "\t" . $row['Probe1'] . "\n";
    }
    mysql_close($con); ?>
```

And the php file for the chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/> 

        <title>Highstock & multiple</title>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var chart;
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        var options = {
                            chart: {
                                renderTo: 'container',
                                defaultSeriesType: 'line',  
                                marginRight: 130,
                                marginBottom: 25
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Temperature Tunnel',
                                x: -20 //center
                            },
                            subtitle: {
                                text: '',
                                x: -20
                            },
                            rangeSelector: {
                            buttons: [
                            {
                                type: 'all',
                                text: 'all'
                            }, {
                                type: 'week',
                                count: 1,
                                text: '1w'
                            }, {
                                type: 'day',
                                count: 1,
                                text: '1d'
                            }, {
                                type: 'hour',
                                count: 18,
                                text: '18h'
                            }, {
                                type: 'hour',
                                count: 12,
                                text: '12h'
                            }, {
                                type: 'hour',
                                count: 6,
                                text: '6h'
                            }]
                            },
                            xAxis: {
                                type: 'datetime',
                                tickWidth: 0,
                                gridLineWidth: 1,
                                labels: {
                                    align: 'center',
                                    x: -3,
                                    y: 20,
                                    formatter: function() {
                                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%b %H:%M', this.value);
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            yAxis: {
                                title: {
                                    text: 'Celsius degrees'
                                },
                                plotLines: [{
                                    value: 0,
                                    width: 1,
                                    color: '#808080'
                                }]

                            },
                            tooltip: {
                                formatter: function() {
                                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%d-%b %H:%M', this.x) +': <b>'+ this.y + '</b>';
                                }
                            },
                            legend: {
                                layout: 'vertical',
                                align: 'right',
                                verticalAlign: 'top',
                                x: -10,
                                y: 100,
                                borderWidth: 0
                            },
                            series: [{
                                name: 'Probe1'
                            }]
                        }
                        jQuery.get('datatest2.php', null, function(tsv) {
                            var lines = [];
                            traffic = [];
                            try {
                                // split the data return into lines and parse them
                                tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                                jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                                    line = line.split(/\t/);
                                    date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                                    traffic.push([
                                        date,
                                        parseInt(line[1].replace(',', ''), 10)
                                    ]);
                                });
                            } catch (e) {  }
                            options.series[0].data = traffic;
                            chart = Highcharts.stockChart (options);
                            setInterval(function() { tsv; }, 30000);
                            pollChart.series[0].setData(data);
                        });
                    });
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

        </body>
        </html>
```

Can you help me to find and fix the mistake?
Thanks!
Alex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of your first example and the JSFiddle that you posted, I would try something like this:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        load: function () {
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                <?php
                    for($i = 0 ;$i<count($rawdata);$i++){
                ?>
                        series.addPoint([<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["Time"];?>,<?php echo $rawdata[$i]["Probe1"];?>], true, true);
                <?php } ?>
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I have no idea whether your PHP code there is actually retrieving the data that you wanted, I have simply copied it from your example and made the assumption that that part of the code was ok.

The key here is the `chart.events.load` property, this takes a function that fires once the chart has finished loading. By calling `setInterval` here, your function will fire continuously after the chart finishes loading the first time.

By calling `series.addPoint`, your chart will redraw every time a new point is added, which I believe is what you want.

More information is available [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.load) about the `load` property.

Comment: Dear Daniel. I have added the database connection code to my question. I have implemented your code (you can see now), with 90 seconds for updates. But after 90 seconds, the chart is freezed and the Chrome process begin to eat a lot of resources from the system. I think I have something running wrong into the code, but I can't see. Can you help me again?

Comment: I discovered something strange. I was looking for more information about addPoint and I made some changes, and playing, but it was unsuccessful. I delete my table2 and begin with less value. So I have returned to the code I pasted here and know I can see changes in the chart: Every 15 seconds (if I use 15000 miliseconds in the code), Chrome take more resources from the system, and the 2 or 3 older values in the chart dissapear. So is like the chart go more and more smaller.

Comment: Hi @Alex, sorry I didn't get back to you earlier. Unfortunately I can't really help with performance issues in the browser. It depends on a lot of things, from the amount of points you are trying to chart, to performance issues at the database end if the query is sub-optimal. One thing you might try if you have a lot of points to chart is the Highcharts performance boost at http://www.highcharts.com/articles/2-news/175-highcharts-performance-boost

Comment: Thanks for your comment back! Really is not a problem with the browser or the number of points (are less than 150). Is a question about the code, I think. I was reading more, and I want to change the connection php code to mysql, for separate "x" and "y" points from the query, and test again with addPoint. But if someone have more ideas, tell me please :)